# MS Chart zooming with multiple chart areas

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, mschart

I am having an issue when trying to set up zooming into a chart area. I have made multiple charts before where the user selects an area and it zooms in normally, but in this particular application I have 3 chart areas in one chart control and when I make a selection in one chart area, all of the other chart areas zoom to that area as well.
[image: example]

You can see that all three chart areas are selected when I am only selecting the first one.

The only code I have for each one of these chart areas is

```
Chart1.ChartAreas[i].CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = True;
Chart1.ChartAreas[i].CursorY.IsUSerSelectionEnabled = True;
Chart1.ChartAreas[i].AxisX.Zoomable = True;
Chart1.ChartAreas[i].AxisY.Zoomable = True;
```

*NOTE*: I have this set for each individual chart area, I just didn't want to write too much.

---

So I was wondering if anybody knows of any possible way to make each individual chart area zoomable with a selection of the mouse and not zoom the other 2 chart areas when I make a selection in one?
Thank you so much for your time and consideration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the issue was and why all the chart areas were zooming at the same time --

I had `Chart.ChartArea[i].AlignWithChartArea` set to other charts to make the visuals a bit better. Apparently that binds the zooming as well for some reason.